# next js module.exports sass and static

Tags: webpack, next.js

Im trying to figure out how to setup my next.config.js file to use sass as well as exportPathMap, here is what I have:

```
module.exports = {
  withSass() {},
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
    };
  },
};
```

But it looks like the withSass() doesnt run, do I need to wrap the exportPathMap with withSass()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the `exportPathMap` part, but `withSass` should be use like this : (its an HoC)

```
module.exports = withSass({
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Not mentioned anywhere, very helpful. thanks @Fabien Greard